# Access element using xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I would like to get the links to all of the elements in the first column in this page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Alabama).

I am comfortable using BeautifulSoup, but it seems less well-suited to this task (I've been trying to access the first child of the contents of each tr but that hasn't been working so well).

The xpaths follow a regular pattern, the row number updating for each new row in the following expression:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[' + str(counter) + ']/td[1]/a'
```

Would someone help me by posting a means of iterating through the rows to get the links?

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
urls = []

while counter < 100:
     urls.append(get the xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[' + str(counter) + ']/td[1]/a'))
     counter += 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't just leaving out the row number work out fine and select the first children of each row? That's basically how XPath works, you don't identify single elements, you identify a pattern that the elements you want match.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see what you mean.  You are referring to using xpath, and leaving out the row number, selecting all the links in the first column?

Comment: Besides that, it's not particularly clear what your question is. If it's "how do I use XPath with lxml" in the first place the documentation should cover that, as in it's right there in the menu. If it's crafting the XPath expression, what I said should help, but ideally you should poke around things experimentally. As in, start with a simpler expression, print out what it matches, then add to it. Also remember that you don't necessarily need to use *one* XPath expression for the entire query, you're working in Python not XSLT, so it's fine if you do this in multiple steps.

Comment: 'Ideally', but just looking to the community for a quick fix here in a larger project. The answers are very helpful and thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the example on how you can get all of the links from the first column:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Alabama"
response = requests.get(URL)

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(response.text, parser)

for row in tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr'):
    links = row.xpath('./td[1]/a')
    if links:
        link = links[0]
        print link.text, link.attrib.get('href')
```

Note, that, `tbody` is appended by the browser - `lxml` won't see this tag (just skip it in xpath).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
from lxml import html

urls = []

parser = html.parse("http://url/to/parse")
for element in parser.xpath(your_xpath_query):
    urls.append(element.attrib['href'])
```

You could also access the `href` attribute in the XPath query directly, e.g.:

```
for href in parser.xpath("//a/@href"):
    urls.append(href)
```

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to does not seem to have content at the XPath you specified. Here is a different XPath which does the job:

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html as LH
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0")]
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Alabama'
xpath = '//table[@class="wikitable sortable"]//tr/td[1]/a/@href'
doc = LH.parse(opener.open(url))
urls = doc.xpath(xpath)
print(urls)
```

Comment: @alecxe: Ah. No problem. Fixed. Basically, just add `td[1]` to the XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking to something like

```
urls = []
while True:
    try:
        counter = len(urls)+1
        (node,) = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[' + str(counter) + ']/td[1]/a')
        urls.append(node)
    except ValueError:
        break
```